# Using IntelliJ with X11 Forwarding

Tags: macos, ubuntu, intellij-idea, android-studio, x11

I'd like to use IntelliJ with X11 forwarding over SSH.  I can confirm I can X forwarding working by running `xeyes` but when I run IntelliJ I don't see anything.  What setting do I have to configure?

The host is Ubuntu 14 and the client is Mac OS X.

Comment: Would you please change the question to state that this is an OSX specific problem?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you don't have IntelliJ running already in your Ubuntu box. The default setting actually only allows for one running instance. So if you close IntelliJ and run it using X11, it should just work.